# configuring vsftpd

Tags: 12.04, server, ftp

I've got a problem connecting to my remote server using vsftpd.  From the documentation, it seems there should be little to no configuration necessary if I just want to connect with my username/password.  However, I keep getting an error message saying

```
530 Login incorrect.
Login failed.
```

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The vsftpd version is current. Below is my configuration; I've deleted all the commented text so it's easier to read here.  Can anyone see what my problem is?

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my vsftpd.conf file(only the settings).Logging with ubuntu user id and password.
In "vsftpd.chroot_list" are the users from(ubuntu users) which can connect to the ftp server.

```
listen=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=002
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
async_abor_enable=YES
ftpd_banner=PAP server.
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
ls_recurse_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

Update:
Instead of using vsftpd for ftp server try using openssh-server.
I've moved on from vsftpd to openssh and the ftp client connects without any issues.

[SSH Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH)

And then you can connect to the sftp server that openssh has build in with:

-Ftp connection type-> SFTP

-Server ip

-Port depending if you changed your ssh port or not,default is 22

-Server username and password for connection.

Hope it helped.

Comment: I've altered my settings to exactly mimic yours, but I'm still getting `421 Service not available`.  Ideas?

Comment: Try connecting to the ftp while a ssh connection to the server is active.Meaning:connect to the server using ssh and leave the connection open and then try using the ftp.I am having a similar issue.Can not find a answer for that.

Comment: I have same problem, and I used your config file above, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Check my updated answer.